How to get `bitarray` module in Python 3.11, iPadOS 17.6?
I wanted to use the bitarray module. I typed the command $ pip3 install bitarray. It was successfully installed, but it reported an error when I tried to import it.
Code:
import bitarray

Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/70D7D19F-D760-465F-9349-B9B457DDB1E0/Documents/TestCode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bitarray
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from bitarray._bitarray import (bitarray, decodetree, _sysinfo,
ImportError: dlopen(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/_bitarray.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/_bitarray.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/_bitarray.cpython-311-darwin.so), but incompatible platform (have 'macOS', need 'iOS')), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/_bitarray.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/_bitarray.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/CA6D7B01-BD6D-4954-A540-18C24905E5B4/home/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitarray/_bitarray.cpython-311-darwin.so), but incompatible platform (have 'macOS', need 'iOS'))

I thought the problem is that I installed the bitarray 3.0.0 version, which does not support my iPadOS 17.6 operating system. I tried to install the 2.7.3 version like this:$ pip3 install bitarray==2.7.3. Bitarray 2.7.3 was successfully installed (it also said the 3.0.0 version was successfully uninstalled), but the same error message appeared when I tried to import bitarray.
I’m using Python 3.11, what should I do?

you need to do pip3 install bitarray==2.7.3 to install a specific version of a library. If you use space pip will interpret 2.7.3 as a second library to install, use == instead

That works! But I still can’t use bitarray, maybe it is not about which version.

PyPI packages generally cannot directly run on mobile devices because mobile operating systems (iOS and Android) do not natively support Python execution.
However you can use Juno or Pythonista which provides a Python development environment for iPad and iPhone.
